# Haskell, again. Illegal types?

Tags: haskell, types

I'll just post the code and the compiling error.

```
module Mov where
import Data.List
import System.IO

mov = do putStr motion

motion :: [Char] -> [Int, Int] -> [Int, Int]
motion [] c ≃ c
motion (i : it) c = if i == 'L' || i == 'l' then putStr ((head c) +1, tail c) : motion it
else if i == 'U' || i == 'u' then putStr (head c, ((tail c) + 1)) : motion 
else if i == 'R' || i == 'r' then putStr (((head c) + 1), tail c) : motion 
else if i == 'D' || i == 'd' then putStr ((head c), ((tail c) - 1)) : motion it
 else "instrução invalida" putStr c
```

And the compiling errors:

```
mov.hs:10:19:
Illegal type: ‘'[Int, Int]’ Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds

mov.hs:10:33:
Illegal type: ‘'[Int, Int]’ Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds
```

Comment: This code is wrong in so many ways - please start  reading on some basic haskell syntax - like http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Comment: `[Int,Int]` cannot exist - maybe you meant `(Int,Int)` also `putStr` expects a `String` as input

Comment: I've tried a tuple (Int, Int) and I get the same type of compiling error.

Comment: a) please be mannered, b) if you write in a forum try to write a meaningful question - your post contains no information what you have already researched or worked on

Comment: And if the code is so wrong tell me what is wrong with it!!!! Pure semantics? Logical structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95149/discussion-between-epsilonhalbe-and-baitillus).

Comment: I've researched the Haskell documentation, the wikipedia, a wiki specific to haskell, this forum and many other pages. Nothing seems to be explicit or even implicit on this type of compiling error. If my question is not meaning full then I don't know what a question is.

Comment: I cant write on the chat. It says i dont have level to do that. sorry epsilonhalbe. I have learned a lot from you. Organization of ideas and concepts manly. I owe you one. Thank you very much!

Comment: @baitillus: your code (_and_ attitude) is wrong on so many levels, I literally don't know where to start... but in any case: it says `[Int, Int]` is an illegal type, and that's all there is to the compilation error — the type `[Int, Int]` is nonsensical; and of course you provided no insight whatosever to what this code is intended to do, nor what you might think this error means, which would have shed some light into how you think and your level of experience, etc, aiding others in helping you.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about what this code is supposed to achieve, so it's hard to correct it in the right direction. In the question you should have stated your goal so to provide some context.

I'll just point out a few errors in the code as it is.

```
motion :: [Char] -> [Int, Int] -> [Int, Int]
```

`[Int, Int]` is not a type. If you want a list of integers, just use `[Int]`; if a pair of exactly two integers, use `(Int, Int)`.

```
motion [] c ≃ c
```

The `≃` should be `=`. (How did `≃` end up there?)

```
motion (i : it) c = if i == 'L' || i == 'l' then putStr ((head c) +1, tail c) : motion it
else if i == 'U' || i == 'u' then putStr (head c, ((tail c) + 1)) : motion 
else if i == 'R' || i == 'r' then putStr (((head c) + 1), tail c) : motion 
else if i == 'D' || i == 'd' then putStr ((head c), ((tail c) - 1)) : motion it
 else "instrução invalida" putStr c
```

First, indentation matters. The `else`s should be indented more than `motion ...`.

Second, you can't `putStr` in a pure function -- no side effects are allowed unless you return an `IO` type.

Third `tail c + 1` makes no sense: the tail of a list is a list, and not a number, so you can't `+1` that.

Fourth, the the error case I'd use `error "instrução invalida"`.

Fifth, sometimes you recursively call `motion` without an argument.

Moreover, in

```
mov = do putStr motion
```

you can't print a function: provide some arguments for that.

Comment: `mov = putStr . motion` would also make sense.

Comment: @TheodoreLiefGannon unfortunately `motion` takes two arguments, so it does not work :-(

Comment: Ah, missed that. Would still work with just one argument supplied, though: `mov xs = putStr . motion xs`. Of course there's always `mov = (putStr .) . motion` but... yeah, ew. ;)

Comment: All those nested ifs really cry out for guards.

Comment: @dfeuer, or rather for a list of actions: `lookup (toUpper c) ...`.

Comment: @user3237465, I missed the fact that the alternatives were different cases of the same letters. I'd smash case and use pattern matching.

Comment: In GHC, `[Int, Int]` (better `'[Int, Int]`) is a type of kind `[*]`. Not what the OP wants, but a type.